# Is it Visual Studio 2013 or what???? - "Identifier not found"

Tags: c++

I am reading Bjarne's - Principles and Practice Using C++ (I found it very useful for beginners, since I am one) and there is an example calculator. I type the functions it has in the book but use a different organization: Header files. I have a problem with one in particular:

```
#ifndef Primary_h
#define Primary_h

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "Token.h"
#include "Expression.h"

//Deal with numbers and parentheses
//USES:expression() and get_token
double primary(){
    Token t = get_token();
    switch (t.kind){
    case '(':
    {
        double d = expression();
        t = get_token();
        if (t.kind != ')')
            cerr << "')' expected\n";
        return d;
    }

    case '8': return t.value;
    default: cerr << "primary expected\n";
    }
}

#endif
```

When I compile i get:

```
error C3861: 'expression': identifier not found
```

even though I add the `expression` header file which is:

```
#ifndef Expression_h
#define Expression_h

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "Token.h"
#include "Term.h"

//Deal with + and -
//USES: term() and get_token
double expression(){
    double left = term();                               //read and evaluate an expression
    Token t = get_token();                              //get the next token
    switch (t.kind){                                    //see which kind of token it is
    case '+': left += term(); t = get_token(); break;   //read and evaluate a Term, then do an addition
    case '-': left -= term(); t = get_token(); break;   //read and evaluate a Term, then do a subtraction
    default: return left; break;                        //return the value of the expression
    }
}
#endif
```

As you can see in `expression` I use another similar header file: `Term.h`, which works fine (in compilation). The line of error is indicated in Bold. Can you please help me?

Comment: Don't suppose that the compiler is wrong. First, consider that *your code* is wrong. And give the line relevant to the error message you've got.

Comment: Frankly, the first thing that leaps odd to me is both of those functions being *implemented* in header files.

Comment: This is a small project. You'll be much better by having a *single* header file (with only declarations in it) for your project, and a *few* source files. You can put more than one class or function in a source file, and you probably should.

Comment: you may wanna check term.h for any missing ; or }, in my experience it is in 99.99% of the cases a code problem, not a compiler problem

Comment: Maybe you can tell us where you got the files from - they don't look quite like what Stroustrup has on his downloads for the book: http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/  If you didn't download them, but rather typed them in yourself, please give a clear, complete (but still small) compilable example that reproduces your problem.  You might need to give details on the command used to invoke the compiler as well.

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch - Thanx, I am doing that right now
WhozCraig - I had to do it that way since each of these: Expression, Primary and Term use each other and I get the same error for all of them, would you like to see that?

Comment: For example, perhaps `Token.h` or `Term.h` have a copy/paste error and is using the name `Expression_h` as the include guard macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual, this "magical" behavior is *most likely* (read: *definitely*) caused by circular inclusion of header files.

Include guards break infinite recursion, but a side-effect of that is that some header file that looks "included" at the first sight, is not actually included (skipped by the guard).

In your case include guards did their job and prevented `Expression.h` from being properly included into `Primary.h`. That is why `expression` remains undeclared in `Primary.h`.

But why on Earth are you writing function definitions in header files??? I'm sure you couldn't have gotten that idea from Bjarne's book. If you move the function definitions to `.cpp` files and leave mere *declarations* in the headers, the problem will go away by itself (albeit it is not an excuse to include headers in circular fashion).

Comment: Thank you very very much, that was very informative, I made a single .cpp file including the function definitions of my functions and a header containing only the declarations. Works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular dependency somewhere, please check all your header files and header guards, if they are correct or not.